# DesGit - merging branch required origin

Tags: git

I am trying to merge a branch into a feature branch i have created.

Master
  - `featureBranchCurrent`

Develop
  - `featureBranchDesired`

So i am trying to merge `featuredBranchDesired` into `featuredBranchCurrent`

while on `featureBranchCurrent`:

git merge `featureBranchDesired`

But git requires that i use git merge

```
origin/featureBranchDesired
```

Is this correct and if so why?

Comment: is 'git merge featureBranchCurrent' a typo? Should it be 'git merge featureBranchDesired'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever checked out `featureBranchDesired` locally?

If not then there is no local branch with that name, so you either need to create it first (by checking it out with `git checkout featureBranchDesired`) or say you want to merge from the remote branch with that name, which is `origin/featureBranchDesired`

Comment: Sorry that was a type - i have fixed.  I am trying git merge featureBranchDesired but it does require origin/featureBranchDesired

Comment: I have never checked it out locally no.  So this is the reason?

Comment: Yes, if you haven't checked it out locally then there is no such branch as `featureBrachDesired`, you need to create a local branch by checking it out or merge from the remote branch `origin/featureBranchDesired`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use:

```
git merge origin/featureBranchCurrent
```

if you are pulling featureBranchCurrent from a remote location.

If you want to merge your featureBranchDesired branch into your featureBranchCurrent, then you'll need to do:

```
git checkout featureBranchCurrent
git merge featureBranchDesired
```

At which point your featureBranchCurrent will have merged in changes from featureBranchDesired.